# Order Id is jumped up in opencart

Tags: php

I have a website in opencart the order id is jumping up.
means if a person has order something on website and his order id is 49 the order id of the next order should be 50 but it is shown as 51 or 52.
When I check in the database table oc_order it shown the same order for the missing order no.

```
class ModelCheckoutOrder extends Model {    
public function addOrder($data) {
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` SET invoice_prefix = '" . $this->db->escape($data['invoice_prefix']) . "', store_id = '" . (int)$data['store_id'] . "', store_name = '" . $this->db->escape($data['store_name']) . "', store_url = '" . $this->db->escape($data['store_url']) . "', customer_id = '" . (int)$data['customer_id'] . "', customer_group_id = '" . (int)$data['customer_group_id'] . "', emp_name = '" . $this->db->escape($data['emp_name']) . "', emp_ID = '" . $this->db->escape($data['emp_ID']) . "', email = '" . $this->db->escape($data['email']) . "', mobile_no = '" . $this->db->escape($data['mobile_no']) . "', fax = '" . $this->db->escape($data['fax']) . "', payment_emp_name = '" . $this->db->escape($data['payment_emp_name']) . "', payment_emp_ID = '" . $this->db->escape($data['payment_emp_ID']) . "', payment_company = '" . $this->db->escape($data['payment_company']) . "', payment_company_id = '" . $this->db->escape($data['payment_company_id']) . "', payment_tax_id = '" . $this->db->escape($data['payment_tax_id']) . "', payment_address_1 = '" . $this->db->escape($data['payment_address_1']) . "', payment_address_2 = '" . $this->db->escape($data['payment_address_2']) . "', payment_city = '" . $this->db->escape($data['payment_city']) . "', payment_postcode = '" . $this->db->escape($data['payment_postcode']) . "', payment_country = '" . $this->db->escape($data['payment_country']) . "', payment_country_id = '" . (int)$data['payment_country_id'] . "', payment_zone = '" . $this->db->escape($data['payment_zone']) . "', payment_zone_id = '" . (int)$data['payment_zone_id'] . "', payment_address_format = '" . $this->db->escape($data['payment_address_format']) . "', payment_method = '" . $this->db->escape($data['payment_method']) . "', payment_code = '" . $this->db->escape($data['payment_code']) . "', shipping_emp_name = '" . $this->db->escape($data['shipping_emp_name']) . "', shipping_emp_ID = '" . $this->db->escape($data['shipping_emp_ID']) . "', shipping_company = '" . $this->db->escape($data['shipping_company']) . "', shipping_address_1 = '" . $this->db->escape($data['shipping_address_1']) . "', shipping_address_2 = '" . $this->db->escape($data['shipping_address_2']) . "', shipping_city = '" . $this->db->escape($data['shipping_city']) . "', shipping_postcode = '" . $this->db->escape($data['shipping_postcode']) . "', shipping_country = '" . $this->db->escape($data['shipping_country']) . "', shipping_country_id = '" . (int)$data['shipping_country_id'] . "', shipping_zone = '" . $this->db->escape($data['shipping_zone']) . "', shipping_zone_id = '" . (int)$data['shipping_zone_id'] . "', shipping_address_format = '" . $this->db->escape($data['shipping_address_format']) . "', shipping_method = '" . $this->db->escape($data['shipping_method']) . "', shipping_code = '" . $this->db->escape($data['shipping_code']) . "', comment = '" . $this->db->escape($data['comment']) . "', total = '" . (float)$data['total'] . "', affiliate_id = '" . (int)$data['affiliate_id'] . "', commission = '" . (float)$data['commission'] . "', language_id = '" . (int)$data['language_id'] . "', currency_id = '" . (int)$data['currency_id'] . "', currency_code = '" . $this->db->escape($data['currency_code']) . "', currency_value = '" . (float)$data['currency_value'] . "', ip = '" . $this->db->escape($data['ip']) . "', forwarded_ip = '" .  $this->db->escape($data['forwarded_ip']) . "', user_agent = '" . $this->db->escape($data['user_agent']) . "', accept_language = '" . $this->db->escape($data['accept_language']) . "', date_added = NOW(), date_modified = NOW()");




    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "order_history SET order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "', order_status_id = '" . (int)$order_status_id . "', notify = '1', comment = '" . $this->db->escape(($comment && $notify) ? $comment : '') . "', date_added = NOW()");

        $order_product_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'");

        foreach ($order_product_query->rows as $order_product) {
            $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET quantity = (quantity - " . (int)$order_product['quantity'] . ") WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$order_product['product_id'] . "' AND subtract = '1'");

            $order_option_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_option WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "' AND order_product_id = '" . (int)$order_product['order_product_id'] . "'");

            foreach ($order_option_query->rows as $option) {
                $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option_value SET quantity = (quantity - " . (int)$order_product['quantity'] . ") WHERE product_option_value_id = '" . (int)$option['product_option_value_id'] . "' AND subtract = '1'");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Show some code on how you're saving a record, we can't guess what the problem is.

Comment: Unless you implemented some customizations for Opencart, you need to ask Opencart's support, not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

this is because there is a difference between what you see in the database itself and what you see in the orders admin page. and this difference is due to the fact that opencart stores something called a missing order id, and that happens for example one someone fills all the details and then by mistake he just reloads the checkout  page and then he just press the "confirm" button. at this case for example in the orders admin page he booked two orders number and you will only see the second number - ofc the number of order ids skipped is the same as the number of missing orders stored by opencart itself.

if you want to test this go to checkout page and fill all orders and then confirm it, at this case you wont see any difference, however if you go to checkout page fill all info and then reload the page and then just press confirm you will see that the order id will skip one number.

in opencart database you wont see missing order ids, because opencart insert an order in the database only if it was confirmed.